# How do you log serverless errors to cloudwatch?

Tags: node.js, amazon-cloudwatch, serverless

I am using serverless to create lamda functions on aws. I would like any unhandled errors to go to cloudwatch.

How can I set this up? I have tried using `winston` - but I cannot use a `process.on unhandled` errors (serverless seems to overide my handling and exiting the code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a simple `console.log()` should have your logs showing up in Cloudwatch. You can also click on the monitoring tab in AWS to access Cloudwatch.

This should help:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-cloudwatchlogs.html